# K mean clustering based on attribute constrain

Tags: r

Attribute-Based K-Means Algorithm

I have spatial point datasets with values, I want to identify unique set of nearest points (non-overlapping) where cumulative sum value will be nearest to X (defined amount). here is the example

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(geosphere)

# example data from the thread
x <- c(-1.482156, -1.482318, -1.482129, -1.482880, -1.485735, -1.485770, -1.485913, -1.484275, -1.485866)
y <- c(54.90083, 54.90078, 54.90077, 54.90011, 54.89936, 54.89935, 54.89935, 54.89879, 54.89902)
weight <- c(0.5, 0.7,0.8, 0.5,0.4, 0.9,1,0.85,1)

xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), data.frame(ID=seq(1:length(x))),
  proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))

# use the distm function to generate a geodesic distance matrix in meters
mdist <- distm(xy)

hc <- hclust(as.dist(mdist), method="complete")

xy$clust <- cutree(hc,k=3)
```

#in this data i want to get 3 cluster of the nearest points where cumulative sum of weight will reach near 2

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about how to give a reproducible example. stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. just added one of the R data as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach to get attributed weighted cluster for predefined K

```
#if you have predefined K you can find list of cluster to reach predefined value of attribute

library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(geosphere)

# example data from the thread
x <- c(-1.482156, -1.482318, -1.482129, -1.482880, -1.485735, -1.485770, -1.485913, -1.484275, -1.485866)
y <- c(54.90083, 54.90078, 54.90077, 54.90011, 54.89936, 54.89935, 54.89935, 54.89879, 54.89902)
weight <- c(0.5, 0.7,0.8, 0.5,0.4, 0.9,1,0.85,1)
dat=data.frame(cbind(x,y,weight))
dat$index=seq(1,9,1)


xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), data.frame(ID=seq(1:length(x))),
  proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))

# solution of predefined k=3

mdist <- distm(xy)
mdist=cbind(mdist, index = dat$index)
newcluster=list()
for(k in 1:3){
  dat$dist=mdist[,k]
  newdata <- dat[order(dat$dist),]
  newdata$cum=cumsum(newdata$weight)
  newdata=newdata[newdata$cum<=2,]
  index=sort(newdata$index)
  dat=dat[!(dat$index %in% newdata$index),]
  mdist=mdist[!(mdist[,"index"] %in% newdata$index),]
  mdist= mdist[,-(index)]
  newcluster[[k]]=newdata}
```